# Having trouble using load() and save() methods stored outside of main.java

Tags: java, android

Here is what my io.java file looks like, which contains the class "io", which holds my methods load() and save().

```
 package com.myschedules;

 //FILE I/O
 import java.io.*; 
 import android.content.Context;

 public class io {

Context asdf;

//save file 
public  void save(String filename, String data) { 

    try { 
        FileOutputStream fos = asdf.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
        fos.write(data.getBytes()); 
        fos.close(); 
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) { 
    }
}


//load file
public  String load(String filename) {
    try { 
         FileInputStream fis = asdf.openFileInput(filename);
         BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
         String line = null, input="";
         while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) input += line; 
         reader.close(); fis.close();
         return input; 
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) {
         return ""; 
    }
 }
```

}

When I got to call these methods in main, it looks like this:

```
 io login_io = new io();
 String login_preferences = login_io.load("login_preferences.dat");
```

Unfortunately, this just causes my app to crash at start up.  How can I store my load() and save() functions in a separate file as to not clutter up my main. Compartmentalization is extremely important for my own organization.  This is so simple in other languages with the #include or import calls, but I'm lost here.

EDIT:

Okay, now I've got another issue... this is from within MainActivity.java.  I am wanting to do some file I/O after a button is clicked.  However, it ends up producing this error over the "io login_io = new io(this);":

"The constructor io(new View.OnClickListener(){}) is undefined"

```
 cmd_login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        public void onClick(View v) 
        {

            io login_io = new io(this);
            String login_preferences = login_io.load("login_preferences.dat");
```

Comment: What do you mean with main? Do you know in Android there are activities right?

Comment: maybe you have to set the corresponding rights in your manifest XML file to access the filesystem

Comment: The manifest includes calls <uses-permissions> for both the READ and WRITE functionalities.

Comment: also, by main, I mean MainActivity.java. The first (and only) activity in my program.

Comment: if main is MainActivity extends Activity you should update your question accordingly.

Comment: Change to "new View.OnClickListener()". Or "Source -> Organize Imports" as we discussed earlier.

Comment: The 'this' inside the new io(this) should be changed to new View.OnClickListerner()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The crash is probably a `NullPointerException` on the Context variable `asdf`.
You need to set `asdf` in the constructor.

**Add the constructor like this**:

```
// Constructor
public io(final Context context) {
    asdf = context;
}

public void save... // do not change.
public String load... // do not change.
```

You will also have to add the Activity/Context 'this' variable to your instantiation of the `io` class in your MainActivity class like this:

**Change**:

```
io login_io = new io(); // Bad :(
```

**To this**:

```
io login_io = new io(this); // Good :)
```

P.S. I understand from your comment below that MainActivity.java is an Android Activity class (i.e. "`class MainActivity extends Activity`") so that 'this' is the correct type. This is good news.

Comment: public io is a class, though.

Comment: class MainActivity extends Activity is what mine says

Comment: Yes. "io" is a class. Add the requested constructor "public io(final Context context)" alongside "save()" and "load()" within io.java. Change your main Activity my modifying the call to "new io()" with the addition of the Context parameter.

Comment: The original post references "main", so I assumed "main.java". "MainActivity" is actually a better name. I presume that "new io(this)" is located in "MainActivity.java". If not, then some more modifications may be necessary.

Comment: So now I should have load(), save(), and io() methods?

Comment: Corrrect: You should now have "load()", "save()", and "io()" methods in the file "io.java".     P.S. There are other ways to call functions in external files. For example, you could make your "save()" and "load()" functions "static". In that case, you would have to pass "Context asdf" as a parameter into each of those functions. Then, you would not need the additional "io(Context)" constructor. Both styles are acceptable.

Comment: So with the third io() method, where is that used in terms of calling my save() or load() methods from MainActivity.java?

Comment: Only a small change is required to your original code in MainActivity.java. All you have to do is change "new io();" to "new io(this);".

Comment: Shouldn't the code inside the io() method be like this:

public io(final Context context) {
    Context asdf = context;
}

Comment: By adding the constructor line, do I still need the Context asdf; line, or does that go away?

Comment: No. No. No. To both your previous suggestions. a) Implement the "io()" constructor exactly as I said with "asdf = context". This will set the class variable 'asdf' so it is available to save() and load(). And, b) leave the class level definition "Context asdf;" as you originally had it.

Comment: Yeah, I don't get why you were downvoted.  I'm thankful as hell for all your help here man.

Comment: Aww. Thanks. Feel free to mark as as correct if you get your code working.

Comment: Just edited the main post, the io.java file no longer has any errors, but I cant test it until I can instantialize it properly.... can you take a look there?

Answer (score 1):

When are you assigning a context to asdf?  If you're not, you'd be hitting a NullPointerException.

Comment: How do I assign a context to asdf?

Comment: In order to assign "context" to "asdf", you must pass "context" into the "io" class somehow. The most obvious way to do this is through a constructor to the "io" class, as suggested in another answer.

Comment: Does there need to be any call to the method io() in either the save() or load() methods?  I don't understand how these methods are supposed to know to use a Context called asdf if they aren't referenced..

Comment: Ah, but they are referenced in the MainActivity.java class when you call "io login_io = new io(this)". That is how Context is passed into the "io" class.

Comment: by creating the constuctor, it now says that inside both the load() and save() methods, that asdf cannot be resolved.

Comment: You need to keep the definition "Context asdf;" where you had it, and only assign to it in your constructor: "asdf = ..."

Comment: You need to add "import android.content.Context;" to "io.java". This can be done automatically with Source -> Organize Imports. Or, use hotkeys: Mac Cmd-Shift-O, Win Ctrl-Shift-O.